# After insatalling cordova-plugin-google-analytics plugin for Android, app build showing error for 'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter'

Tags: android, ionic3

I am facing problem after installing cordova-plugin-google-analytics  in my ionic v3 project. I am getting this error given below.

[image]

Could you please help me anyone to fix the problem for android platform?

My project info details. My project is in IONIC V3.
[image]

Package.Json details below. I used cordova-plugin-firebase and cordova-plugin-firebase-lib these two plugin.

```
{
  "name": "Birdchain",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "author": "Birdchain OU",
  "homepage": "https://birdchain.io",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-preferences": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-update": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/streaming-media": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/user-agent": "~4.10.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "CordovaSMS": "0.0.3",
    "android-referrer-plugin": "git+https://github.com/jonas-m-/android-referrer-plugin.git",
    "angular-font-awesome": "~3.1.2",
    "angular-svg-icon": "~5.1.1",
    "chart.js": "~2.7.2",
    "com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer": "https://github.com/jonas-m-/android-referrer-plugin",
    "cordova": "~8.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-annotated-plugin-android": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-clipboard": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-play-services-version-adapter": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "~1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": "git+https://bitbucket.org/packt-internal/cordova-plugin-app-preferences.git",
    "cordova-plugin-app-update": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-appversion": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cache": "git+https://github.com/tiltshiftfocus/cordova-plugin-cache.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "git+https://github.com/rhanesoghlyan/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#master",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-lib": "^3.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-useragent": "~1.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sms-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-useragent": "git+https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent.git",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent": "https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "~2.8.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "org.apache.cordova.plugin.cache": "https://github.com/tiltshiftfocus/cordova-plugin-cache.git",
    "rxjs": "~5.5.12",
    "socket.io-client": "~2.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.22",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "@types/gsap": "~1.19.2",
    "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.5",
    "gsap": "~2.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "Birdchain",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent": {},
      "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
      "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": {},
      "cordova-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-support-google-services": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "org.apache.cordova.plugin.cache": {},
      "cordova-sms-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "CordovaSMS": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-update": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase-lib": {},
      "cordova-plugin-analytics": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, share you package.json and see the versions of firebase installed.

Comment: @1antares1- I added package.json. Please see above.